# How to make panels with a node reference argument

Tags: nodes, panels, comments, views

I have a multi-user site. When a new user registers, several nodes (such as gallery node, etc.) are automatically created for him/her.

There is a panel page for each user that displays a profile of its owner. The panel is composed of various view panes.

Very much like in other community sites, a visitor to the profile page will be able to leave comments (text + pictures.)

To that effect, **and hoping this is the right approach,** I am trying to include in the panel a comment form. Comment forms are attached to their respective nodes so that comments left on John's panel page do not show on Jack's panel page. Comments will be displayed under the form in a view. The view is obviously universal and the same for all panel pages.

Now, on to the comment form. There is a node, specially for comments, created at the time the user registers.

How do I include the comment form of that node in a panel context knowing that it has to be different for each user?

I see that a node context can be passed into the panel. However, it requires a node ID. So that limits it to one node.  Does it support some kind of token so that a different node ID loads on different users pages? If so, how would I write it?

If i am using the wrong approach on this, how should I go about it?

Any idea anyone?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a similar feature on my site: when a user registers, several nodes of different content types are created specifically for that user.  I also use Panels.

To (somewhat) easily link the content with the user, I used the [Relation](https://drupal.org/project/relation) module, which integrates with [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules).  After I created the content upon account registration, I created relations between the user and the content (all using Rules-- if you do this, you'll need to make a rule set and create the content in one rule before creating the relations in a following rule; otherwise, you'll get some weird errors).

Then, without using Panels contexts, I simply created content panes in Views that pull in the content by adding relations (from the Relation module) as relationships (in the Views UI).

The challenge of this approach is that setting up rules to fetch the relations and loop through them is pretty complex.  It might be easier to use the [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/Entityreference) module, which has Rules integration, but when I was building my site a year ago it was broken so I used the more complex Relation module instead.

Comment: Wow...  I would never have thought of this! I see i still have some work to do. Thank you for your time and advice. I will post the results here once I am done. Again, thank you. :)

Comment: I tried everything. I followed the tutorial for the Entity Reference, created an Entity Reference field for the the user profile and added the referenced entity relationship to the view. 
As soon as I make the relationship required, regardless of the contextual filter, nothing shows. I tried this in the pane view and the (newly created) Entity Reference view.

I also tried it in reverse, adding an Entity Reference field to the comment node and repeated the procedure, but nothing.

Comment: How did you set the value of the Entity Reference field?  Are you sure you set it correctly?

Comment: On user account setting: Widget type: Select list, Default value: comment form. Target type: Node. Target bundle: Comments on profile pages. Mode: Simple No, I am not sure at all it is set up correctly. I guess if it were it would work! LOL :)
I am trying all sorts of combinations/permutations but to no avail.

Comment: I am trying to get the logic straight here. A) There is ONLY ONE node that will receive ALL the comments left by everyone to everyone across the site. Right? B) If so, then it is a matter of sorting who left a comment to whom. Now, in my available relationships I only have "author" as users. That means I can only set a contextual filter relating to the author, i.e., all the comments one user left across the site (and that works.) Now the trick is to filter those comments by recipients. Still correct?
(continued below...)

Comment: (...continued) C) I guess this is where Entity Reference plays its part. So, the Entity Reference field must be added to the user settings, not the node or comment settings. Correct? It will help me to know if my logic is correct for that would prevent me from jumping arround among a myriad of settings and concentrate on the Entity Reference field settings. Again, thank you for your valuable input on this. :)

Comment: @user14666 No, I think you should have a node per user.  Unless you plan to have a very small number of users, doing everything on a single node will create a mess.  So each user should have his or her own node (automatically created using Rules, perhaps) and an Entity Reference in the user account to that user's specific node.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. A node per user was my original choice. Creating it with Rules when the user registers is easy. The trick is going to have Rules set the Entity Reference to that user's specific node. But I will try. We shall see... :)

Comment: ok, so I set up the user's entity reference field to no default value since there will be one per user. but.. I need to have panel display a different comment form (the one attached to the user's node.) How do I accomplish this since panel only allows a single node ID as context? I am sorry to keep bothering you with this but it looks like a catch 22 situation to me. I guess I still don't see the angle. :)

Comment: @user14666 Instead of a Panels context, you can use a View content pane that has a Contextual Filter which takes the UID (supplied via Panels argument).  Then you can use Views to display everything.

Comment: ok. So, now, I have an entity reference field on users' accounts. I have a new node automatically created when a new user registers (with Rules,) and I have another rule that back links the node to the user's account. I also have a view pane that nicely displays the comments. All this works well. I still need to set the relationships but what about the comment form? It obviously has to be the newly created node's form  How do I pull it into the view or display it in panel?

Comment: Hold on... I think I got it. I found in the panel "Add Content" a "Node from User (on User:Comment reference)" --> node comment form. That appears to segregate the comments on a per user basis. I still need to set the contextual filters for proper display. Will be back soon. :)

Comment: Hmmm... When, in the view pane, I click on the Edit link of  Argument Input (under pane setting) I get a small white window with "Content pane: Choose the data source for views arguments" as a title. Then, it's all white, and under that the Apply and Cancel button. Is that normal behavior? I was hoping to be able to select panels there but there is nothing to select. Other content panes in other views give the option to select "From panel."

Comment: As it turned out, my hosting company had messed up my database. Hence the problem with the blank window. I had to go back almost two weeks to find a backup that did not have that problem. So, I'll be busy rebuilding all I developed during the last two weeks.

Comment: ok. Fixed. I have created the back links again, got the content created when the user registers. It's all good. I have also created a view with a UID from the URL with an argument passed from panels. It seems all good. In order to test the view, I need to include the form into panel too. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: @user14666 This site is not a discussion forum (unlike the forums on Drupal.org); the idea is that each question should answer a specific problem.  If you are having a new problem, please ask a new question.  For more information, see the help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 0):

I have to use this because the site doesn't allow editing of comments for more than five minutes!

Anyway...

I tried everything. I followed the tutorial for the Entity Reference, created an Entity Reference field for the the user profile and added the referenced entity relationship to the view.

As soon as I make the relationship required, regardless of the contextual filter, nothing shows. I tried this in the pane view and the (newly created) Entity Reference view.

I also tried it in reverse, adding an Entity Reference field to the comment node and repeated the procedure, but nothing. Maybe it doesn't work because one is a node and the other a user? I have no idea. I am back to square one.

It's very discouraging. I am back to square one. Anyway, I really appreciate what you've tried to do. Thank you. :)

Comment: If you want to change a comment, you can delete it and add a new one.

Comment: Ok. I hadn't seen the little cross to delete. Thanks for pointing that out.